# More bandwidth-efficient data formats than XML & JSON?

Tags: javascript, .net, ajax, xml, json

When transferring large amounts of columnar data from web server to browser in the JSON or XML format, column names are repeated unnecessarily for every row. What I have to transfer is basically CSV format - ie. multiple rows of data, each with the same field order.

For example, in XML I'd be transferring:

```
<row>
  <name>Frank</name>
  <city>New York</city>
</row>
<row>
  <name>Brian</name>
  <city>Jerusalem</city>
</row>
etc..
```

Same with JSON, field names are repeated unnecessarily, which becomes a lot of extra bytes for no reason.

My question is, are there other standard formats, supported by libraries in Javascript and/or .NET, which I can use to more efficiently transfer this kind of "CSV-like" data set?

Comment: So, why not use CSV? You can also set up your server to gzip the data, which would probably save the most bandwidth.

Comment: Why is this question too broad? There are a very limited number of options available when trying to save bandwidth between server and client; so a limited set of answers.

Comment: If someone can vote to close the question, why can't others vote to reopen it?

Answer (score 1):

Unless you're talking about a LOT of data, it probably doesn't matter that much (bandwidth is cheap, or so I hear).  However, if you're trying to squeeze as much data as possible into the available bandwidth, you do have options.

You could use whatever format you want (XML, JSON), then compress it.  For example, you could use [JSZip](http://stuk.github.io/jszip/).  Advantage: you don't have to transform your basic data structure.

Also, there's nothing to stop you from using CSV if that's format that makes the most sense for your application.  Best to use a library such as [jquery-csv](https://code.google.com/p/jquery-csv/) to handle annoyances like properly quoting strings.  Disadvantage: this isn't really compression; simply a format without a lot of overhead.

All things told, I would probably go with the first approach.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your json format is like below:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Frank",
    "city": "New York"
  },
  {
    "name": "Brian",
    "city": "Jerusalem"
  }
]
```

Why not simply change it to:

```
[
  ["name", "city"],
  ["Frank", "New York"],
  ["Brian", "Jerusalem"]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when transferring large amounts of data via XML from Flash (running on client, similar to JavaScript) and .NET (running on server obviously)

The method I ended up using was;

```
XML > string without whitespace > zip compress > base64 encoded
```

And then on the other side, do the reverse.

In your case, you may just do;

```
CSV > string > zip > base64
```

From memory, I was able to get some really big payloads (approx. 2mb) down to less than 50kb

Comment: just to add, I chose zlib compression because I was able to use it both client (Flash) and server (.NET) sides. I believe zlib is available in JavaScript, as a lib.

Comment: Thanks very much, wasn't aware of JS-based unzip. But why base64 encode - doesn't that just add more bulk to the transfer?

Comment: Yes, adds more bulk but it ensures your data is plain text, otherwise it will be in binary. Was never able to get binary to work, also I saved so much data after compressing, that base64 encoding added comparatively little, especially for the added benefit of debugging via Fiddler. But, if you can do it with binary, do it with binary - its better.

Comment: Also, I have a feeling there are security issues with IIS and binary data; at least on the server I was working on, it freaked out when it saw binary data. That also may not be a problem for you.